# Pydev: Running Eclipse/Aptana debug server on command-line

Tags: eclipse, command-line, pydev, remote-debugging, aptana3

I've found many informations on how to setup an Eclipse/Aptana remote debug server with the GUI.
Is there a way to launch it from command-line ?

There must no need of a GUI in the whole process.
My goal is to setup a remote debug server on a server machine accessed only by command-line.

Thanks.